# Trying to add image to Bing Maps for windows store app

Tags: c#, bing-maps

I'm having an issue adding an image to my map, I'm almost sure it has something to do with how I'm referencing the image.

```
         var uri = new System.Uri("ms-appdata:///Assets/mypic.png");
         Image addPic = new Image { Source = new BitmapImage(uri) };

        addPic.Width = 20;
        addPic.Height = 20;

        MapLayer.SetPosition(addPic, picLocation);
        MapLayer layer = new MapLayer();
        layer.Children.Add(addPic);
        myMap.Children.Add(layer);
```

When I set a breakpoint and try to look at addPic, it shows up as null.
I tried adding addPic in the xaml, but then I run into a problem that it said it was already a child to the grid.

Also, in the properties for myPic, the build action is set to content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alight, I couldn't ever get that method to work, so what I did instead was make a custom xaml class in blend that was just an image on a canvas.

```
<Grid Width="32" Height="32">
    <Image Source="Assets/thePictureToBeDisplayed.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="32"/>
</Grid>
```

Then in my Main screen I created a new instance of that class and added it to the map.

```
         MyImage thePic = new MyImage();

        MapLayer.SetPosition(thePic, picLocation);
        MapLayer layer = new MapLayer();
        layer.Children.Add(thePic);
        myMap.Children.Add(layer);
```